# Bash copy verbose update in Solaris

Tags: bash, solaris

I'm writing some small bash scripts for copiyng certain files/directories in GNU/Linux and Solaris. Everything is OK in Linux, but cp command hasn't the same options in Linux and Solaris.

Copy command is something like this:

```
cp -ruv $source $dest
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve copy verbose and copy update in Solaris. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `cp` under Solaris doesn't have that option.  `man solaris` should reveal that.

Are you comfortable making your script depend on [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync.)?

Or, if possible, you can install the [coreutils](http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html#coreutils) package and use GNU's cp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Yeah, fist thing I did was check man pages. I'd prefer not to install anything and find a solution with default tools

Comment: Your options really are, use a different tool, or do something more complicated parsing the output of `find` and checking if you should copy the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue myself and found that gcp takes care of it too. I've made installing coreutils part of my standard system setup.

I run these on a new Solaris install:

```
pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
pkgutil -U
pkgutil -i -y coreutils
pkgutil -a vim
pkgutil -i -y vim
pkgutil -i -y findutils
```

Remember to add the path - and the documentation path - to your profile, and possibly to the system profile at /etc/profile:

```
# Set the program path
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/sfw/sbin:/usr/openwin/bin:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local
export PATH

# Set the documentation path
MANPATH="$MANPATH:/usr/share/man:/opt/sfw/man:/opt/csw/man"
export MANPATH
```

It sounds like you might be new to Solaris - as I am relatively new. I also do these, which shouldn't affect anything.

I set VIM as the default editor instead of VI - it's compatible, but has more features, including ANSI color, and some terminal emulators will pass your mouse clicks and scrolling through for even more flexibility:

```
# Set the default editor
EDITOR=vim
export EDITOR
```

Then if you are still using the default prompt that doesn't say anything, you might want to add some information - this version requires a Bash shell:

```
# Set the command prompt, which includes the username, host name, and the current path.
PS1='\u@\h:\w>'
export PS1
```

Answer (score 0):

To recreate verbose mode, you can tee the output to the controlling terminal (`/dev/tty`) while the `stdoout` output of `tee` itself is passed to `cp` via `xargs`.

```
find /some/source/directory -type f | \
  tee /dev/tty | xargs -I {} cp {} /copy/to/this-directory/
```

Replace the `find` with whatever you like, so long as it passes the paths to the files to be copied through the pipe to `tee`.

Tested on a standard Solaris 10 system without extra GNU utils.